# Where are the generic parameters saved for Async calls? Where to find its name or other information?

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

Here is my test code: the extension method `GetInstructions` is from here: https://gist.github.com/jbevain/104001

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            typeof(TestClass)
             .GetMethods()
             .Where(method => method.Name == "Say" || method.Name == "Hello")
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(method =>
                {
                    var calls = method.GetInstructions()
                    .Select(x => x.Operand as MethodInfo)
                    .Where(x => x != null)
                    .ToList();

                    Console.WriteLine(method);
                    calls.ForEach(call =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t{call}");
                        call.GetGenericArguments().ToList().ForEach(arg => Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{arg.FullName}"));
                    });
                });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class TestClass
    {
        public async Task Say()
        {
            await HelloWorld.Say<IFoo>();
            HelloWorld.Hello<IBar>();
        }

        public void Hello()
        {
            HelloWorld.Say<IFoo>().RunSynchronously();
            HelloWorld.Hello<IBar>();
        }
    }

    class HelloWorld
    {
        public static async Task Say<T>() where T : IBase
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"Hello from {typeof(T)}.")).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public static void Hello<T>() where T : IBase
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello from {typeof(T)}.");
        }
    }
    interface IBase
    {
        Task Hello();
    }

    interface IFoo : IBase
    {

    }

    interface IBar : IBase
    {

    }
}
```

Here is run result as the screenshot shown:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task Say()
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder Create()
        Void Start[<Say>d__0](<Say>d__0 ByRef)
                ConsoleApp1.TestClass+<Say>d__0
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task get_Task()
Void Hello()
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task Say[IFoo]()
                ConsoleApp1.IFoo
        Void RunSynchronously()
        Void Hello[IBar]()
                ConsoleApp1.IBar
```

**NON-ASYNC calls got correct generic parameters, but ASYNC calls cannot.**

[image]

My question is: where are the generic parameters stored for ASYNC calls?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Operand is of type RuntimeMethodInfo, not IFoo. You can find out more about that class here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/ab.html#b097ac305d5a8300,references

Comment: @Jon I've read sourcecode before posting this, but it used this a internal function `internal string ConstructName` from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtimehandles.cs,e1d2424681ba48a5,references , which blocked me to find out interface name.

Comment: Check out my answer below, you can call GetGenericArguments() and you can iterate that then find IFoo from that.

Comment: @Jon Thanks a lot for your response, I immediately realized I made a wrong example code. my problems are in async code, I cannot get correct parameters from async calls. I've updated my example code. Hopefully you can help again. Thousands of thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `async` methods are not that easy.

The C# compiler will generate a comprehensive state machine out of an `async` method. So the body of the `TestClass.Say` method will be completely overwritten by the compiler. You can read [this great blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) if you want to dive deeper into the async state machinery.

Back to your question.

The compiler will replace the method body with something like this:

```
<Say>d__0 stateMachine = new <Say>d__0();
stateMachine.<>4__this = this;
stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = stateMachine.<>t__builder;
<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
```

`<Say>d__0` in this code is a compiler-generated type. It has special characters it its name to prevent you from being able to use this type in your code.

`<Say>d__0` is an `IAsyncStateMachine` implementation. The main logic is contained in its `MoveNext` method.

It will look similar to this:

```
TaskAwaiter awaiter;
if (state != 0)
{
    awaiter = HelloWorld.Say<IFoo>().GetAwaiter();
    if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
    {
        // ...
        builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    awaiter = this.awaiter;
    state = -1;
}

awaiter.GetResult();
HelloWorld.Hello<IBar>();
```

Note that your `HelloWorld.Say<IFoo>()` call is now here, in this method, not in your original `TestClass.Say`.

So, to get the generic type information from your method, you will need to inspect the `MoveNext` state machine method instead of the original `TestClass.Say`. Search for the call instructions there.

Something like this:

```
Type asyncStateMachine = 
    typeof(TestClass)
    .GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .FirstOrDefault(
        t => t.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null 
        && typeof(IAsyncStateMachine).IsAssignableFrom(t));

MethodInfo method = asyncStateMachine.GetMethod(
    nameof(IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext),
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

List<MethodInfo> calls = method.GetInstructions()
    .Select(x => x.Operand as MethodInfo)
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .ToList();

// etc
```

Output:

```
Void MoveNext()
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task Say[IFoo]()
                ConsoleApp1.IFoo
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
        Boolean get_IsCompleted()
        Void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted[TaskAwaiter,<Say>d__0](System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter ByRef, <Say>d__0 ByRef)
                System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter
                ConsoleApp1.TestClass+<Say>d__0
        Void GetResult()
        Void Hello[IBar]()
                ConsoleApp1.IBar
        Void SetException(System.Exception)
        Void SetResult()
```

Note that this code depends on current `IAsyncStatMachine` implementation internals. If the C# compiler changes that internal implementation, this code might break.

Answer (score 2):

You can try getting the generic method info and that way you can find the  IFoo generic type argument from this (code taken from the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod)):

```
private static void DisplayGenericMethodInfo(MethodInfo mi)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n{0}", mi);

        Console.WriteLine("\tIs this a generic method definition? {0}", 
            mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition);

        Console.WriteLine("\tIs it a generic method? {0}", 
            mi.IsGenericMethod);

        Console.WriteLine("\tDoes it have unassigned generic parameters? {0}", 
            mi.ContainsGenericParameters);

        // If this is a generic method, display its type arguments.
        //
        if (mi.IsGenericMethod)
        {
            Type[] typeArguments = mi.GetGenericArguments();

            Console.WriteLine("\tList type arguments ({0}):", 
                typeArguments.Length);

            foreach (Type tParam in typeArguments)
            {
                // IsGenericParameter is true only for generic type
                // parameters.
                //
                if (tParam.IsGenericParameter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}  parameter position {1}" +
                        "\n\t\t   declaring method: {2}",
                        tParam,
                        tParam.GenericParameterPosition,
                        tParam.DeclaringMethod);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}", tParam);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I immediately realized I made a wrong example code. my problems are in async code, I cannot get correct parameters from async calls. I've updated my example code. Hopefully you can help again. Thousands of thanks!

Comment: Your output looks correct "System.Threading.Tasks.Task Say[IFoo]()                  ConsoleApp1.IFoo"  IFoo is the generic argument you want, no?

Comment: No, check out the outputs for first test method TestClass.Say(), which uses async calls, then all parameters go strange.

Comment: I see, let me look into that

Comment: @Dongdong sorry man I was unable to find the stack to get IFoo from your code. I ran through several iterations but there is obviously more to AsyncTaskBuilder than I know.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway.  async calls are compiled to a different way. it looks the `GetInstructions` should be improved as well.